# Lenovo laptop won't turn on

Tags: laptop, motherboard, power-supply, battery

I'm having a weird issue with a lenovo V130 laptop that wont turn on. The behavior is as follows.

I plug the AC adapter, and the led next to the plug turns on. When I push the power button the power light on it turns on, fan starts running, and that's about it... Nothing on the screen, no beeps or noises or indication that anything's going on. The fan stops after 5-10 seconds, but the power light stays on. I know the usual suspects, so I tried:

- Hard reset
- Pushing the recovery button (This is a Lenovo feature in some of their laptops to perform a system reset)
- Connecting it to an external display
- Trying with a different AC adapter
- Opening the case and:
  => Disconnecting the battery
  => Disconnecting the SSD
  => Disconnecting the DIMM
  => Disconnecting PCI wireless minicard
  => Removing and replacing CMOS battery
  => Cleaning any dust/dirt (doesn't seem to be an issue)

Every time I got the same result: Computer seems to turn on, nothing is shown on the screen, fan stops running after a few seconds, power light remains on...

Since it all looked like a motherboard issue to me, I decided to replace it for a spare one I found on ebay. Seller has good reputation and confirms it has been tested successfully. So I made the replacement and... still same issue.

I'm a bit puzzled now. Any ideas?

Comment: Take it to a repair shop for a proper diagnosis.

Comment: It's not exactly clear from your question: have you tried to turn it on with the battery disconnected?

Comment: @gronostaj, yes I did that. Same result. I also checked battery and AC plug with a tester and both are giving the expected voltage output. Only thing I can think of now is replacing the DIMM (I don't have a spare around) or maybe a fan issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out it was a faulty DIMM module. I would have expected to get some kind of error shown in the screen, flashing LED, beeping... but no much clue was given to indicate a memory issue. In the end I had to find by the means of trial and error with every component.

Shame that I didn't try that before replacing the motherboard, I would have saved myself some time and money.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).